# How to get the node as well as node values using XPath

Tags: java, dom, xpath, xml-parsing

I am using xPath to get the node values. Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<address>
    <buildingnumber> 29 </buildingnumber>
    <street> South Lasalle Street</street>
    <city>Chicago</city>
    <state>Illinois</state>
    <zip>60603</zip>
</address>
```

This is the code that i am suing

```
DocumentBuilder builder = tryDom.getDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDocument = tryDom.getXmlDocument(builder, file);

XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = factory.newXPath();

XPathExpression xPathExpression = null;

String expression7 = "//address/descendant-or-self::*";

try {

    xPathExpression = xPath.compile(expression7);
    Object result = xPathExpression.evaluate(xmlDocument,XPathConstants.NODESET);
    printXpathResult(result);

} catch (XPathExpressionException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

public static void printXpathResult(Object result){

    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

        Node node = nodes.item(i);
        String nodeName = node.getNodeName();
        String nodeValue = node.getNodeValue();

        System.out.println(nodeName + " = " + nodeValue);

    }

} //end of printXpathResult()
```

The output that i am getting is

```
address = null
buildingnumber = null
street = null
city = null
state = null
zip = null
```

I am expecting this output

```
address = null
buildingnumber =  29
street = South Lasalle Street
city = Chicago
state = Illinois
zip = 60603
```

Why i am getting null although buildingnumber and other has values ? How can i get my desired output ?

Thanks

**EDIT
--------------------------------------------------------------**

```
 public static void printXpathResult(Object result){

    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

        Node node = nodes.item(i);
        String nodeName = node.getNodeName();
        String nodeValue = node.getTextContent();

        System.out.println(nodeName + " = " + nodeValue);

    }

} //end of printXpathResult()
```

After this i am getting the following output

```
address = 
 29 
 South Lasalle Street
Chicago
Illinois
60603

buildingnumber =  29 
street =  South Lasalle Street
city = Chicago
state = Illinois
zip = 60603
```

Why i am getting address = 29 .... . I think it should be `address = null` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the DOM API, `getNodeValue()` is specified to *always* return `null` for element nodes (see the [table at the top of the JavaDoc page for `Node`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html)). You probably want [`getTextContent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29) instead.

However, note that for the `address` element, `getTextContent()` will not give you null, rather you'll get the concatenation of all the text node descendants, including whitespace. In a real use case you would probably use `descendant::` rather than `descendant-or-self::` in the xpath so you don't have to handle the parent element specially, or use something like

```
descendant-or-self::*[not(*)]
```

to limit the result to leaf elements (those that do not themselves have any element children).

Comment: @Basit I've added some more detail.

Comment: hhmm thanks :). I have another question but i think i use another post for it. As far as this question is concern you explain me really well :) Thanks :)